# Getting error when trying to do the customized message in jQuery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have been trying many times with JQuery for validating errors using customized messages, but I am still confused that where I am making the mistake.I have tried with the normal validating messages, but when I tried with the customized, it shows me an error.

Below is the sample code which i have tried so far and unsucessful in executing it.

```html
<form id="myform">
  <tr>
    <td class="alpha">username</td>
    <td>
      <input type="username" type="text" value="">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <br/>
  <tr>
    <td class="alpha">postcode</td>
    <td>
      <input type="postcode" type="text" value="">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

```js
$.validator.setDefaults({
  submitHandler: function() {
    alert("submitted!");
  }
});

$document.ready(function() {
  $("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
      password: "required",
      postcode: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3
      }
    },
    messages: {
      username: {
        required: "*Please enter a username",
        minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
      },
      postcode: {
        required: "Field PostCode is required",
        minlength: "Field PostCode must contain at least 3 characters"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: *"when I tried with the customized, it shows me an error"* - exactly what error?

Comment: The issue got resolved. Thanks for your response @Sparky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, your code would not work with the default messages either.

Please read my comments in the code...

```
rules: {
    password: "required",  // <- input with name="password" (where is "password"?)
    postcode: {            // <- input with name="postcode"
        required: true,
        minlength: 3
    }
},
messages: {
    username: {     // <- input with name="username"
        required: "*Please enter a username",
        minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
    },
    postcode: {     // <- input with name="postcode"
        required: "Field PostCode is required",
        minlength: "Field PostCode must contain at least 3 characters"
    }
}
```

1. The `rules` and `messages` objects' parameters are keyed by the `name` attribute of the input element.  Your input elements do not contain any `name` attributes.  The plugin mandates that all form inputs contain a unique `name`, and the plugin will not work without these.
2. You have invalid values for the `type` attribute.  There are no such things as `type="username"` and `type="postcode"`; and you erroneously have more than one `type` attributes on each input, `<input type="username" type="text" value="">`
3. In your case, you don't even attempt to define any rules for a `username` field.  You only have `password` and `postcode` within the `rules` object.

Fix your invalid HTML markup and JavaScript...

- Remove all extraneous `type` attributes from each input.
- Add a unique `name` attribute to each input.
- Only reference your `name` attributes within `rules` and `messages` objects.

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/2tx6u7wf/](https://jsfiddle.net/2tx6u7wf/)**